# SVN Branching Tagging related

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a few questions regarding SVN and it's working process:

1. Is Branch and Tag are same or different?
2. If both are the same, can anyone differentiate the creation process of both separate branch and tag?
3. How can we tag based on revision number?
4. Suppose we have tree structure like this:

> ```
>    Ex: Repository path
>        experimental(root)
>          sample
>          sample1
>          sample2
>          sample3
> ```

Suppose we have 4 branches like above given example for that how can we create tags.
And if I want to tag sample1 and sample3 at a time can we do it once or we have to do it separately for each individual.

Can you please guide me if I am wrong in asking anything wrong?

Answer (score 1):

**For your 1st and 2nd questions**

Branches and Tags are different only in what they represent. The actual process that svn uses to create them is the same.

**Branch:** Branches should be used when you plan on making changes to your trunk. The code in the branch is likely to be changed over time and possibly merged back into the trunk.

**Tag:** Tags are generally used more as a bookmark, pointer or roadmarker for your project. If you have just completed a sprint cycle for instance it is common to create a tag to represent the state of the code at that time.

**3rd Question**

I personally prefer command line for my svn interactions, but if you are using Tortoise svn to create your Tag. You want to open up the Tortoise Branch/Tag box where you will specify the location of the code you want to create a Tag from and then specify the destination (you should take some time to think about your directory layout in svn something like having a spot for Trunk, Tags, and Branch in a way that makes sense). If you want to specify the revision there is a radio button about 2/3s the way down the dialog box called **Specific revision in repository** select that and in the box next to it type in the number of the revision you want to use. Essentially branches and tags are just a copy command that svn executes so it will just copy the code it sees at that revision to the location that you specify to be the "TAG" location. The actual location is totally up to you.

**4th Question: Creating a Tag from Branch**

Creating a Tag from a branch is almost identical to creating a Tag from Trunk. You open the same dialogue box that I mentioned above and follow the same steps with the only difference being that you specify the branch location as your code to Tag from instead of the trunk.

**Future Reading**

If you are going to do more work with svn you will want to check out some more in-depth literature. There are a lot of different sources out there one is [red-bean](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.2/index.html)